# DevExpress Gridview Disabling & Coloring Cells

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm working with DevExpress Gridview control.

I have two distinct issues:

I have four rows of Data (always first 4 records in Dataset) that certain cells always must not be edited. These rows should have certain columns with a grey background showing they are disabled.

Right now, the only thing I can use is `GridView2_RowCellStyle`:

```
Dim View As GridView = sender

If e.Column.FieldName = "Percent" Or e.Column.FieldName = "PGPct" Or e.Column.FieldName = "VGPct" Then
    If e.RowHandle = 0 Or e.RowHandle = 1 Or e.RowHandle = 2 Or e.RowHandle = 3 Then
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Silver
    End If
End If
```

and

`GridView2_ShowingEditor`:

```
If GridView2.FocusedColumn.FieldName.ToString = "Percent" Or GridView2.FocusedColumn.FieldName.ToString = "PGPct" Or GridView2.FocusedColumn.FieldName.ToString = "VGPct" Then
    If GridView2.FocusedRowHandle = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```

However, when a user sorts or groups data, these rows can change, which makes choosing them via FocusedRowHandle or RowHandle impossible.

How do I make sure these cells are always disabled and have their background grey, even when sorted or grouped?

Comment: why do you not add a unbound column and then according the column value do your disable and color functionality..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.GetDataSourceRowIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataSourceRowIndextopic) method to obtain the actual index of your underlying data source. This index does not depend on sorting, grouping, filtering etc. in your `GridView` and always return the same value for the same row.
For example:

```
Private Sub gridView2_RowCellStyle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RowCellStyleEventArgs) Handles gridView2.RowCellStyle
    Dim View As GridView = sender

    If e.Column.FieldName = "Percent" Or e.Column.FieldName = "PGPct" Or e.Column.FieldName = "VGPct" Then
        If View.GetDataSourceRowIndex(e.RowHandle) < 4 Then
            Dim colors = CommonSkins.GetSkin(UserLookAndFeel.Default).Colors
            Dim textColor = colors.GetColor(CommonColors.DisabledText)
            Dim backColor = colors.GetColor(CommonColors.DisabledControl)

            e.Appearance.ForeColor = textColor
            e.Appearance.BackColor = backColor
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things you can do to make this work.

1. Add a property (and hence a column) to your bound domain object and call it RowNumber
2. When your data is populated, number the RowNumber sequentially so that the object itself keeps track of what row it's in.  Better yet, make it part of the object with a static variable so it auto-increments
3. Rather than using `RowCellStyle` you can now use the format conditions right from the Grid designer -- it's a codeless way to accomplish the same thing
4. As far as locking the rows, if you are using a binding source, use the `CurrentChanged` event to selectively make those columns readonly for certain rows.  In effect, you are switching the read-only property of the column based on which row is selected, which will prevent editing of certain rows

Rather than going into agonizing details on any of these, I trust you can let me know if you're not clear on any of them.  I'm a C# guy, but I'm pretty sure a mocked-up example on C# would be clear enough for you to translate to VB.net.

-- EDIT 12/15/15 --

On item 1, assuming your bound object is a Domain Object/POCO/whatever, if you add one property:

```
private int _RowNum;
public int RowNum
{
    get { return _RowNum; }
}
```

And just make sure you either assign the value when you gather the data or have your constructor do it:

```
private static _Serial = 1;

public MyDomainObject()
{
    _RowNum = _Serial++;
}
```

or -- if you want to do it after the fact:

```
int serial = 1;
MyDomainObjectList.Foreach(x => x.RowNum = serial++);
```

For Item 4, I imagined you have a Binding Source, and if you fire the `CurrentChanged` event on the binding source:

```
bindingSource1.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(bindingSource1_CurrentChanged);
```

it could look something like this:

```
private void bindingSource1_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDomainObject curr = (MyDomainObject)bindingSource1.Current;
    bool locked = curr.RowNum >= 1 && curr.RowNum <= 4;

    colPercent.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly =
        colPGPct.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = locked;
}
```

This doesn't have anything to do with formatting (that is handled by my suggestion #3), but it will selectively lock or unlock the column based on which row is selected.  Since the user can't edit a row he's not in, this will accomplish your goal of making certain rows uneditable.

I do apologize for the C#.  I know you asked a VB question, but I thought it would be easier for you to read my C# than for me to guess what the VB syntax looks like.

See if any of this makes any more sense, or if I can further clarify.  This is sort of a hard one to speculate on, so I understand if it's a lost cause.

Comment: Examples of 1 and 4 would be helpful, I'm totally lost, sorry :-\

Comment: Added some examples.  Check out @nempoBu4's response -- I didn't know that one, but if it works it sounds like it will be a short answer to your problem

Comment: Hambone, your right, his was a quicker fix. I still VERY MUCH appreciate your assistance in matter, without you guys I would have been lost! :D